# Why is there an ADDRESS for the ingress-service? What's the use of that ADDRESS?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I deploy my cluster on GKE with an Ingress Controller

I use [Helm](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#using-helm) to install the following:

- Installed **[Ingress Controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx)**
- Deployed Load Balancer Service (Create a Load Balancer on GCP as well)

I also deployed the **Ingress Object** (Config as below)

---

Then I observed the following status ...

The **Ingress Controller** is exposed (By Load Balancer Service) with two endpoints: 35.197.XX.XX:80, 35.197.XX.XX:443

These two endpoints are exposed by the Cloud load balancer.
I have no problem with it.

However, when I execute `kubectl get ing ingress-service -o wide`, it prints out the following info.

```
NAME              HOSTS             ADDRESS       PORTS     AGE
ingress-service   k8s.XX.com.tw   34.87.XX.XX   80, 443   5h50m
```

I really don't under the use of the IP under the ADDRESS column.

I can also see that Google add some extra info to the end of my Ingress config file about load balancer IP for me.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
   ....(ommitted)
spec:
  rules:
  - host: k8s.XX.com.tw
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: client-cluster-ip-service
          servicePort: 3000
        path: /?(.*)
      - backend:
          serviceName: server-cluster-ip-service
          servicePort: 5000
        path: /api/?(.*)
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - k8s.XX.com.tw
    secretName: XX-com-tw
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 34.87.XX.XX
```

According to [Google's doc](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer#step_4_visit_your_application), this (**34.87.XX.XX**) looks like an external IP, but I can't access it with http://34.87.XX.XX

---

My question is that since we already have an external IP (35.197.XX.XX) to receive the traffic, why do we need this ADDRESS for the **ingress-service**?

If it's an internal or external IP ADDRESS? 
What is this ADDRESS bound to?
What exactly is this ADDRESS used for?

Can anyone shed some light? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If you simply go take a look at the documentation you will have your answer.

What is an ingress ressource: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#what-is-ingress

So following the doc:

> Ingress exposes HTTP and HTTPS routes from outside the cluster to services within the cluster. Traffic routing is controlled by rules defined on the Ingress resource.

To be more precise on cloud provider, the ingress will create a load-balancer to expose the service to the internet. The cocumentation on the subject specific to gke: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer

That explains why you have an external ip for the ingress.

What you should do now:

- If you don't want to expose HTTP or/and HTTPS ports just delete the ingress ressource, you don't use it so it's pretty much useless.
- If you are using HTTP/HTTPS ressources, change your service type to nodePort and leave the management of the load balancer to the ingress.

My opinion is that, as you are deploying the ingress-controller, you should select the second option and leave the management of the load-balancer to it. For the ingress of the ingress-controller, don't define rules just the backend to the nodePort service, the rules should be defined in specific ingress for each app and be managed by the ingress-controller.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.

In here https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#types-of-ingress

It says: "Where 107.178.254.228 is the IP allocated by the Ingress controller to satisfy this Ingress."

But I am still not sure if this IP address belongs to the cloud load balance or the nginx ingress controller (pod)

Comment: My question is actually that why there is another IP for the ingress-service (except for the external one of the cloud load balancer)?

I am sorry if this seems to be a very stupid question. it's just that I've studied the various layers of IPs, such as VM IP, Cluster IP, and Pod IP and this seems to be something different ..

Comment: So there is a mistake in your question, you are speaking of "Load Balancer Service" for the exposition of your ingress-controller... And in that case it's normal for it to create a new external ip as LoadBalancer services on provider create a LB...

Comment: @suren If you use an ingress controller hosts don't need to be defined at the L7 level... you can leave the controller doing the job or there is no need to use one (that's not recommanded but it works)... Where I said there was a mistake was in using the 'Load Balancer Service'... A LoadBalancer service is a service that will create a L4 Load balancer on google with ports of service available. Please read all the answer... I recommand changing the Service from LB to NodePort to resolve issues... If the issue is not there as it seems to be in the question, then there is a mistake...

Comment: Hi @night-gold , are you saying that my current setup is incorrect?

The thing is that I used Helm to install the Ingress on GKE, and it installed everything for me, and if I accessed from the Cloud load balancer, everything works.

Comment: I don't really have a problem with this setup. I just want to know what type of IP (34.87.XX.XX) this is.

It looks like an external IP, but I cannot access it on any ports. I just need to know why it works like this?

Comment: It'd be nice if you can answer this question, but I can totally understand if you don't since this might take you a lot of time to explain. Thanks anyway!

Comment: My current guess is that the IP (34.87.XX.XX) is assigned by GKE, but when I tried to access it, it can only access the services on the VM, not the services inside the containers of the VM. That's why you said I should use NodePort since it'll open a port on the VM. Am I going in the right direction?

Comment: That's why I hate helm... Using it doesn't mean you are doing it ok, take a look at the chart to just grasp the complexity of the what you are using... So again... If you use a Ingress resource it create a lb with an external ip... If you use a service type load balancer it creates a lb with an external ip...Have a look at the GCP console to figure how the ip addresse are linked to your configuration...